# EXC_BAD_ACCESS questions

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, exc-bad-access

I am making a poetry app in which users can write your poems and save them to a file. When I click on the UITextView to add and edit text it instantly causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Can somebody please help me as to why this is happening.

This is what I have in the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextView *newPoemTextView;
    UIImageView *newPoemTextViewBackground;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *newPoemTextView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *newPoemTextViewBackground;
-(IBAction)closeKeyboard;
@end
```

and this is what I have in the .m file

```
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize newPoemTextView;
@synthesize newPoemTextViewBackground;

-(IBAction)closeKeyboard {
    // This part will write the information to the file
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentTXTPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedText.txt"];
    NSString *savedString = newPoemTextView.text;
    [savedString writeToFile:documentTXTPath atomically:YES];

    //This part hopefully closes the keyboard correctly, cross fingers
    [newPoemTextView resignFirstResponder];

}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"newPoemBackground.png"];
    [newPoemTextViewBackground setImage:image];

    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage
                                                                 imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = background;
    [background release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Just letting you know `newPoemTextViewBackground` was never synthesized.

Comment: Added that in now but it still gives me the same error when the keyboad opens.

Comment: **If you have a crash, post the backtrace.**

Comment: There must be something missing, since the code seems alright. Make sure that your delegate in the interface builder is either unset or set to the proper class (file owner?). Also make sure that the IBAction outlets on the text view are not referencing something that has been removed........ For more help you should provide the stack trace of your crash

Comment: Enable NSZombieEnabled for your active executable and let it crash again, what does the console say? And can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I'll be honest and say I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should synthesize both the property in SecondViewController.m file.

```
@synthesize newPoemTextView;
@synthesize newPoemTextViewBackground;
```

You should also implement Keyboard's all method, that will help you a lot.

Comment: I synthesized the other part I'd left out and it crashed as well, I will try implementing the keyboard delegates as was suggester before. Will post back if anything happens.